Quarkus based AWS Lambda native image cold start init phase is slow
I have quarkus-amazon-lambda:3.12.0 based AWS Lambda native image function, which cold start is slow. I'm not expecting it to be like that as the function does not do any complex tasks and the execution time is really fast anyway. The issue is in cold start initialization and I'm not quite sure where the problem is as Quarkus logs shows ~80 milliseconds of initialization time.
2024-07-25 09:56:30,969 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) my-function 0.1-SNAPSHOT native (powered by Quarkus 3.12.0) started in 0.085s. 
2024-07-25 09:56:30,970 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated. 
2024-07-25 09:56:30,970 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [amazon-lambda, cdi]
START RequestId: <uid> Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: <uid>
REPORT RequestId: <uid> Duration: 73.61 ms  Billed Duration: 353 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 51 MB  Init Duration: 278.70 ms    

Basing on lambda execution report, the Init Duration takes most of the time, which, I presume is not something that I can affect somehow.
Non-cold starts are very fast as expected:
START RequestId: <uid> Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: <uid>
REPORT RequestId: <uid> Duration: 1.45 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 52 MB  

So, I'm wondering what can cause such a long initialization time and if there's anything I can do to decrease that? Any thoughts are appreciated!
Configuration:

Quarkus 3.12.0 with aws-lambda and cdi components used
GraalVM native image
512 mb of memory for the Lambda


Your Lambda took about 279ms to initialize so Quarkus taking 85ms isn't bad.  Do you have SnapStart set (assuming you're running with an x86)?  How long does it take on non-cold starts?

@stdunbar Yeah, the issue is indeed with Init phase. I'm running GraalVM native image, if I recall SnapStart is only available for JVM envs.
Non-cold starts are very fast as expected, usually around 2-3 milliseconds.
